# How Do I Determine the Default Orientation of Camera Preview Frames?

Tags: android, android-camera, textureview, android-textureview

I am trying (again) to create camera preview logic that actually works properly, for **all scenarios**:

- any device: phone, tablet, toaster, whatever
- any camera: front-facing, rear-facing, side-facing, dog-facing, whatever
- `android.hardware.Camera` and `android.hardware.camera2`
- portrait and landscape device orientations

Since my `minSdkVersion` is 15, and since I am not especially concerned about performance, I am trying to use a `TextureView`. And, following the advice of fadden in places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175434/115145) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31657474/115145), I am trying to use `setTransform()` on that `TextureView` with an appropriate `Matrix` that:

- orients the preview properly, taking device orientation into account
- fills the `TextureView` completely, at the cost of cropping where the `TextureView` aspect ratio does not match the preview frame aspect ratio
- does not stretch the image, so that a preview of a square item (e.g., a 3" square Post-It Note®) shows up square in the preview

In my case, the `TextureView` fills the screen, minus the status bar and navigation bar.

Starting with the `adjustAspectRatio()` from [Grafika's `PlayMovieActivity.java`](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java), I now have this:

```
  private void adjustAspectRatio(int videoWidth, int videoHeight,
                                 int rotation) {
    if (iCanHazPhone) {
      int temp=videoWidth;
      videoWidth=videoHeight;
      videoHeight=temp;
    }

    int viewWidth=getWidth();
    int viewHeight=getHeight();
    double aspectRatio=(double)videoHeight/(double)videoWidth;
    int newWidth, newHeight;

    if (getHeight()>(int)(viewWidth*aspectRatio)) {
      newWidth=(int)(viewHeight/aspectRatio);
      newHeight=viewHeight;
    }
    else {
      newWidth=viewWidth;
      newHeight=(int)(viewWidth*aspectRatio);
    }

    int xoff=(viewWidth-newWidth)/2;
    int yoff=(viewHeight-newHeight)/2;

    Matrix txform=new Matrix();

    getTransform(txform);

    float xscale=(float)newWidth/(float)viewWidth;
    float yscale=(float)newHeight/(float)viewHeight;

    txform.setScale(xscale, yscale);

    switch(rotation) {
      case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        txform.postRotate(270, newWidth/2, newHeight/2);
        break;

      case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        txform.postRotate(90, newWidth/2, newHeight/2);
        break;
    }

    txform.postTranslate(xoff, yoff);

    setTransform(txform);
  }
```

Here, `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` are the size of the camera preview, and the method itself is implemented on a subclass of `TextureView`. I am calling this method when I have established what the camera preview size is and after the `TextureView` itself is resized.

This appears to be close but not completely correct. In particular, the `iCanHazPhone` hack — flipping the video width and height — is a stab in the dark, as without this, while a SONY Tablet Z2 works well, a Nexus 5 turns out horrible (stretched preview that does not fill the screen).

With `iCanHazPhone` set to `true`, I get good results on a Nexus 5:

[image: Nexus 5, Camera2 Preview, Landscape, Rear-Facing Camera]

[image: Nexus 5, Camera2 Preview, Portrait, Rear-Facing Camera]

With `iCanHazPhone` set to `false`, I get stuff like:

[image: Nexus 5, Camera2 Preview, Portrait, Rear-Facing Camera, Stretched]

Similarly, with `iCanHazPhone` set to `false`, I get good results on a SONY Tablet Z2:

[image: SONY Tablet Z2, Camera2 Preview, Landscape, Rear-Facing Camera]

But if I flip it to `true`, I get:

[image: SONY Tablet Z2, Camera2 Preview, Landscape, Rear-Facing Camera, Stretched]

My current theory is that different devices have different default camera orientations, and depending on that default orientation I need to flip the preview width and height in my calculations.

So, the questions:

1. Is the camera guaranteed (as much as anything involving Android hardware) to have a default orientation that matches the default device orientation? For example, a Nexus 9 works correctly with `iCanHazPhone` set to `true`, indicating that it's not phone vs. tablet but default-portrait vs. default-landscape.
2. Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: Not long ago I received following shortish email related to one of my Camera applications ; _We have found that on devices that have a default landscape orientation, such as Nexus 10, the preview image appears rotated at 90 degrees and stretched._ . What ever that means - remains unknown to me - but what you are explaining here reminded me of this old email. Yet alone how am I supposed to deal with camera rotation on such devices I do not own  :)

Comment: @harism: Well, using [this algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31806201/115145) to detect default-portrait vs. default-landscape devices seems to be working out for me, as an alternative to the hard-coded `iCanHazPhone` value cited in my question. This presumes that my assumptions are correct, which is what the question is really about. But your symptoms definitely sound like what I was seeing in my tests.

Comment: Cool, thank you for letting me know. This helps me fix my app too I hope.

Answer (score 9):

Answer to both of your questions is: use the sensor orientation provided by the Camera/Camera2 APIs to adjust your preview image.

To calculate relative camera rotation to screen (which can be used to transform your preview) I use:

```
static int getRelativeImageOrientation(int displayRotation, int sensorOrientation,
                                       boolean isFrontFacing, boolean compensateForMirroring) {
    int result;
    if (isFrontFacing) {
        result = (sensorOrientation + displayRotation) % 360;
        if (compensateForMirroring) {
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        }
    } else {
        result = (sensorOrientation - displayRotation + 360) % 360;
    }
    return result;
}
```

where **displayRotation** is the current display rotation:

```
static int getDisplayRotation(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            return 0;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            return 90;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            return 180;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**sensorOrientation** for the legacy Camera:

```
Camera.CameraInfo.orientation
```

and for the Camera2:

```
CameraCharacteristics#get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION)
```

You should pass *false* for **compansateForMirror** when calculating camera preview orientation and pass *true* when calculating legacy Camera JPG orientation.

I've tested this across a number of devices - it seems to work, although I cannot guarantee that this is bulletproof ;]

Answer (score 0):

you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/42440513#42440513) for image orientation. Only you need to put the correct surface rotation.